# Uploading Attachments using Rails Paper Clip on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, imagemagick, paperclip

I am deploying a Rails App on DigitalOcean, Ubuntu 16.04.

I have Imagemagick and all paperclip dependency installed. I get the an error when trying to upload and attachment as per below logs.

Is there a certain configuration required? does DIgital ocean allow for storing files on disk?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes Digital ocean allow to save picture / attachment files (pdf or others), I have droplets in DO

you need to setup location for image in your model (for example in your code product.rb), below is sample

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

# attachment for picture image
  has_attached_file :pict, 
    :styles => { :medium => "735x", :thumb => "238x" }, 
    :url  => "/products/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :product => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

end
```

Comment: Thanks, seems was an issue in configuration, now solved